# Correct way to reference CSS in /vendor in Symfony2 and PHPStorm

Tags: css, symfony, phpstorm, vendor

I can correctly reference CSS in a vendor directory like so

```
{% stylesheets  output='css/compiled/main.css'
  '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css'
  '../vendor/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/css/star-rating.css'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

This works. But PHPStorm, my IDE, shows that the file at `/vendor/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/css/star-rating.css` cannot be found. And so highlights it with a warning.

This raises two questions;

1. Is this the best/correct way of referencing CSS (or Javascript) thats in a vendor directory from a Symfony2 point of view? E.g. if there some other syntax I could use?
2. Can I *make* PHPStorm correctly reference the file so I do not get this missing error?

Comment: Regarding the question number 2, you could try to click with the right of the mouse on the vendor folder and then select: Mark directory As --> Resource Root. After PhpStorm should be able to recognise all files inside that directory.